# I want to shorten the route in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am new to Akka HTTP and I wanted to make route for this -> `server/company/:company/authority/:authority/user/:user/region/:region/:regionId/:planTypes`

I have made a route like this ->

```
val route: Route = get {
          pathPrefix("/server") {
            pathPrefix("/company") {
              parameter('company) { company =>
                pathPrefix("/authority") {
                  parameter('authority) { authority =>
                    pathPrefix("user") {
                      parameter('user) { user =>
                        pathPrefix("region") {
                          parameters('region, 'regionId, 'planType) {
                            (region, regionId, planType) =>
                              comleteRequest(tenant, authority, user, region, regionId, planType)
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

but this looks ugly. Is there a better and shorter way to write it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
path("a" / IntNumber / "b" / IntNumber / "c") { 
   (a, b) => _.complete((a + b).toString)
} ~
```

Then, calling it like so:

`http://localhost:8080/a/1/b/2/c`

would return `3`.

More path matcher details here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html

Slash operator will concatenate two matchers and insert slash between them. You can match path segments with literal strings like `server` or extractors like `RegEx`, `LongNumber`, etc. Each extractor will provide a value, so in my example I use 2 int extractors and use a lambda `(a, b)` which will be passed 2 ints.

Comment: Something like this `pathPrefix( "/server" / "company" / "authority" / "user" / "region" / "regionId" / "planType"
        ) {
parameter('company, 'authority, 'user, 'region, 'regionId, 'planType)
}
`
?

Comment: I misread the question. Updated the answer to what you need.